# Better way to customize bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Where can I find a website that I can customize bootstrap 3 more easier like customize it by choosing a color by color picker, change the font/margin/padding size by a range slider, etc..

The link and screenshot below is not that easy to customize and not user friendly.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

[image]

Comment: You can use Sass or LESS to customize Bootstrap. What happens is you get Bootstrap separated into different files, and they are compiled into boostrap.css. You can change most stuff in the variables.css file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bootstrap theme roller, it is more "UI" editor : http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/

Edit : 
I am not involved in any way with the tool above, and I apologize for the short and insufficient answer, I put only this one because that's the one I use.

Couple of similar tools :

http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/#!/editor

http://stylebootstrap.info/

Alternatively, a look to those articles :

http://mashable.com/2013/10/20/bootstrap-editors/

http://thedesignblitz.com/the-best-bootstrap-ui-editors/

Comment: Have a look there : http://mashable.com/2013/10/20/bootstrap-editors/ some are free some not.